# How to allow Eclipse to use more CPU resources

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on Traveling Salesman Problem algorithm.  When I execute the program it takes 3-4 hours to finish (not a big surprise for TSP). However, my Task manager tells that CPU is used only by 5% and ram by 27%. Is it possible to add more CPU resource for program execution, without modifying the code (I am not allowed to modify it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the java program out of eclipse, it runs as an application on its own and not inside eclipse. There is no way to limit or allow more resources inside java. The only way to do it is:

1. From a Virtual Machine
2. When your code can utilise only a limited number of cores and you run it on a multi core machine, in this case modifying the code would be able to utilise more resources.

Since for you none of the above apply - no it's not possible for you.